# Core Data retrive only elements which are not older than 5min

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have an entity with a Date attribute. Now I only want to retrieve entries which are not older than 5min.

I tried this so far.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ContactRequest")

// Create a sort descriptor object that sorts on the "title"
// property of the Core Data object
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "request_time", ascending: true)

// Set the list of sort descriptors in the fetch request,
// so it includes the sort descriptor
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

let originalDate = Date() // "Jun 13, 2016, 1:23 PM"
let calendar = Calendar.current
let limitDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -5, to: originalDate, options: [])

// Create a new predicate that filters out any object that
// doesn't have a title of "Best Language" exactly.
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "request_time > %@", limitDate)

// Set the predicate on the fetch request
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

But xCode says the `calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -5, to: originalDate, options: [])` is unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the api wrong.  Change

```
let limitDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -5, to: originalDate, options: [])
```

to

```
let limitDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -5, to: originalDate, wrappingComponents: true)
```

see:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293453-date

I'm not sure why you have `options` instead of `wrappingComponents`. Perhaps the api has change in a version of swift